# Complex grouping and counting

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data set that looks like

```
Country, Sold, Model
China, 100, Toyota
China, 200, Honda
China, 200, Suzuki
USA, 100, Tesla
USA, 50, Shevi
USA, 50, Lambo
```

And I want to get the output like

```
China, Toyota[20%]; Honda[40%]; Suzuki[40%]
USA, Tesla[50%]; Shevi[25%]; Lambo[25%]
```

So that the data are grouped by country and then for each car model its selling share is being displayed next to the model name.
Is it possible to achieve by using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: I'm sorry this is super hacky, but this is the best I can do.  I'm sure there is a better way, and hope someone is able to show you the better way soon.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Sold, ~Model,
  "China", 100, "Toyota",
  "China", 200, "Honda",
  "China", 200, "Suzuki",
  "USA", 100, "Tesla",
  "USA", 50, "Shevi",
  "USA", 50, "Lambo")
)

model_by_country <- df %>% 
  group_by(Country, Model) %>% 
  summarize(Total_Sold = sum(Sold)) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(Percent_Sold = Total_Sold / sum(Total_Sold)) %>% 
  select(-Total_Sold) %>% 
  ungroup()
model_by_country

##   Country Model  Percent_Sold
##   <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
## 1 China   Honda          0.4 
## 2 China   Suzuki         0.4 
## 3 China   Toyota         0.2 
## 4 USA     Lambo          0.25
## 5 USA     Shevi          0.25
## 6 USA     Tesla          0.5 

# EDITS begin here
format_country_per <- function(country) {
  model_by_country %>% 
    filter(Country == country) %>% 
    mutate(Model_Percent_Sold = paste0(Model, "[", 100 * Percent_Sold, "%]")) %>% 
    .$Model_Percent_Sold %>% 
    paste(., collapse = "; ") %>% 
    paste(country, ., sep = ", ")
}

format_country_per("China")
## [1] "China, Honda[40%]; Suzuki[40%]; Toyota[20%]"
format_country_per("USA")
## [1] "USA, Lambo[25%]; Shevi[25%]; Tesla[50%]"
```

Comment: yeah...I need exactly the shape of output that I mentioned...I am familiar with dplyr, just can't find a way to build the required output...

Comment: Oh sorry about that.  Let me think about this.  I would like to know how to do this too.

Comment: no problem, appreciate your answer anyways. I spent a couple of hours on this already and then sent this question..hope someone can give me a hint...

Comment: I edited the above, but my solution is very hacky.  I'm sure there must be a better way.  Sorry I cannot help more!

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you want the row percentages of a tabulation by Country and Model. This give a table with all possible combinations of those two factors:

```
100*prop.table(                # multiply proportions to get percentages
   with(dat, tapply(Sold, list(Country,Model), sum, default=0)),  #apply sum in categories
                    1)         # the "1" indicates these should be row proportions
       Honda  Lambo  Shevi  Suzuki  Tesla  Toyota
China     40      0      0      40      0      20
USA        0     25     25       0     50       0
```

Comment: not really, I need the exact output that I mentioned in the question description

Comment: 2sov2014 Downvotes are not an effective incentive for further effort.

Comment: Yet I don't consider your answer to be correct or even helpful. hence downvoting.

Comment: Very complex way of thinking ... thank you @42- for your effort !